# How to send STDIN to docker process

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I have a nodemon running in a docker container in development. I have successfully setup live reloading when code changes.

However sometimes I write some code where nodemon crashes. Nodemon can be manually restarted when you type 'rs' (when running locally).

The problem is that within a docker container I can't get it to restart.

I've tried the following with no luck:

`docker exec -it add92j rs` ====>  rs not found

`docker exec -it add92j sh -c echo rs` ====>  just echos rs

I've also tried `docker attach` and then typing rs but it doesn't work.

I've also tried using the shell with `docker exec -it sh`,  getting the process with `ps aux` and then:

`echo rs > /proc/PID/fd/0`

But that also doesn't work. (Note I've tried all the above variants with rs and rs\n and using printf and echo).

In the nodemon github I see that it looks for 'rs\n' to trigger a restart and there is a reference to `SIGUSR2`. Hence I've tried also `kill -12 PID` but that just kills my process. Note that I checked to see that 12 is indeed `SIGUSR2` in my container.

The processes actually running in my container with `ps aux` are:

```
 1 root       0:00 npm
14 root       0:00 sh -c DEBUG=app:* nodemon
15 root       0:00 node /workspace/node_modules/.bin/nodemon
29 root       0:00 sh -c node server/register.js
30 root       0:01 node server/register.js
```

So my question is, how do I send text to stdin for a process in docker?

Comment: What about `echo rs | docker exec -it add92j`?

Comment: Do you run the initial `docker run` for nodemon with the `-ti` option? Before trying `docker attach`?

Answer (score 2):

Running the nodemon container with a `-t` tty and `-i` for stdin allows you to control `nodemon` after a `docker attach`

```
→ CID=$(docker run -dti dply/node-docker-demo-app:nodemon)
→ docker attach $CID
rs
[nodemon] starting `node /app/index.js`
Listening on 8080
^Csigint
```

Comment: This suggestion with `docker attach` helped me in a scenario where `stdin` interaction was not being shown after a container start